# Alter each value returned in a LINQ query at same time as query

Tags: c#, linq

I was wondering if it were possible to perform an operation on every element returned in a LINQ query at the same time as performing the query itself.

Example:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\etc", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(s => (s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd")) 
                                 && 
                                 new FileInfo(s).Length > 500000);
```

finds all files within set criteria, but if I wanted to say trim "C:\" from each string that was returned, could I somehow say s = f(s) after the where clause or would this be a separate foreach each loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the Where statement, you can add this

```
.Select( s => s.Replace(@"C:\",""));
```

That will return the string with C:\ stripped.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) method to do it:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(/* ... */)
                     .Where(/* ... */)
                     .Select(s => s.StartsWith(@"C:\") ? s.Substring(3) : s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do projection using the `Select` clause:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\etc", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
  .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 500000)
  .Select(s => s.Substring(3));
```